# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un varios pesos (ponderaciones) aleatorias para un portafolio?

Tags: python, base-de-datos

Para lograr multiplicarlos con los rendimientos de varias acciones y obtener también la volatilidad y el retorno por cada pesos(ponderaciones distintas. Los pesos o ponderaciones deben sumar 1 en total, para lograr los resultados que se muestran en las imágenes.

```
import random
n = 4
weights = [random.random() for _ in range(n)]
sum_weights = sum(weights)
weights = [w/sum_weights for w in weights]
print(weights)
```

De esta manera logro obtener un pesos/ponderaciones para un portafolio aleatorio, pero necesito generar varios, para lograr generar losretornos y volatilidades. Estoy utilizando python3.7

Ayúdame por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Portafolio con pesos (ponderaciones) aleatorias[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emxil.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por la imagen que muestras me da la sensación de que estás usando Pandas, sea como sea, en vez de recurrir a generar los números aleatorios y luego normalizar podrías plantearte recurrir a usar la [distribución de Dirichlet](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_de_Dirichlet), más que nada porque está implementada en NumPy en [`numpy.random.dirichlet`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.dirichlet.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

acciones = ("AAPL", "MSFT", "XOM", "JNJ", "JPM", "AMZN", "GE", "FB", "T") 
portafolios = 100

random_portafolios = pd.DataFrame(columns=(f"{accion} weight" for accion in acciones),
                                           data=np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(len(acciones)),
                                                                   size=portafolios
                                                                   )
                                 )
```

> ```
> >>> random_portafolios
>
>
>     AAPL weight  MSFT weight  XOM weight  JNJ weight  JPM weight  AMZN weight  GE weight  FB weight  T weight
> 0      0.143335     0.003217    0.238816    0.181586    0.085305     0.029136   0.040685   0.073971  0.203950
> 1      0.246245     0.059063    0.031106    0.017317    0.045353     0.214421   0.127492   0.073092  0.185911
> 2      0.038312     0.006075    0.072793    0.044644    0.016160     0.003624   0.010822   0.520474  0.287095
> 3      0.162723     0.087614    0.049509    0.229241    0.108593     0.012520   0.246437   0.040767  0.062598
> 4      0.209656     0.001035    0.032659    0.044534    0.213237     0.329162   0.041209   0.039650  0.088858
> 5      0.083094     0.174502    0.050812    0.232361    0.069681     0.108613   0.148443   0.025572  0.106920
> 6      0.086768     0.065452    0.053282    0.331260    0.229075     0.123319   0.083669   0.026205  0.000970
> 7      0.011931     0.035522    0.058162    0.148020    0.107266     0.150136   0.116148   0.284715  0.088100
> 8      0.164853     0.237339    0.048541    0.000206    0.249101     0.043880   0.076941   0.054560  0.124579
> 9      0.218513     0.091922    0.049263    0.089317    0.012004     0.115266   0.100703   0.161949  0.161064
> 10     0.324539     0.072584    0.163747    0.113462    0.055219     0.051125   0.015629   0.199281  0.004415
> 11     0.164815     0.055806    0.099620    0.176190    0.377462     0.018619   0.002711   0.036873  0.067903
> 12     0.097081     0.046671    0.029936    0.050734    0.584901     0.079030   0.056469   0.026369  0.028809
> 13     0.212657     0.166719    0.001207    0.031797    0.081146     0.109785   0.230318   0.095456  0.070915
> ..          ...          ...         ...         ...         ...          ...        ...        ...       ...
> 97     0.178339     0.027737    0.201763    0.032170    0.198272     0.073571   0.040056   0.099409  0.148684
> 98     0.009809     0.011152    0.004956    0.159326    0.300231     0.192200   0.152250   0.040051  0.130024
> 99     0.018285     0.126350    0.088724    0.182602    0.003522     0.402781   0.014239   0.145668  0.017831
> ```

Si quieres seguir tu idea original, podrías hacer algo así:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

acciones = ("AAPL", "MSFT", "XOM", "JNJ", "JPM", "AMZN", "GE", "FB", "T") 
portafolios = 100

random_portafolios = pd.DataFrame(columns=(f"{accion} weight" for accion in acciones),
                                 data=np.random.random((portafolios, len(acciones)))
                                 )

# Normalizado de las filas
random_portafolios = random_portafolios.div(random_portafolios.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

Comment: En verdad muchas gracias FJSevila